# Koin - Problem with nested scopes for Android

Tags: android, koin

**Koin Version used : 2.1.0-alpha-8**

I have a FeatureActivity that hosts two Fragments 1) `FirstFragment` and 2) `SecondFragment`

My Module looks like this

```
val featureModule = module {

    scope<FeatureActivity> {

        // FeatureDao
        scoped {
            val appDatabase: AppDatabase = get()
            appDatabase.featureDao()
        }

        scope(named(FirstFragment.SCOPE_ID)) {
            scoped { FirstFragmentRepository(get()) }
            viewModel { FirstFragmentViewModel(get()) } // needs FeatureDao
            scoped { FirstFragmentAdapter(get()) }
        }

        scope(named(SecondFragment.SCOPE_ID)) {
            scoped { SecondFragmentRepository(get()) }
            viewModel { SecondFragmentViewModel(get()) } // needs FeatureDao
            scoped { SecondFragmentAdapter(get()) }
        }

    }
```

With  scope, I want to restrict access to `FirstFragmentRepository`, `FirstFragmentViewModel`etc. to FirstFragment alone and `SecondFragmentRepository`, `SecondFragmentViewModel`etc. to SecondFragment alone.

**Question 1:** However, my ViewModels need FeatureDao to be injected. How do I access `FeatureDao`, given it's a part of parent scope [ FeatureActivity scope]? `FeatureDao` is in ActivityScope because it is necessary for both `FirstFragment` and `SecondFragment`

My Activity looks like this

```
class FeatureActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
         loadKoinModules(featureModule)
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        unloadKoinModules(featureModule)
    }

}
```

and my FirstFragment looks like this

```
class FirstFragment : Fragment() {

    companion object{
        const val SCOPE_ID = "FirstFragment"
    }

    val scope = getKoin().getOrCreateScope(SCOPE_ID, named(SCOPE_ID))
    val viewModel   by lazy {  scope.get<FirstFragmentViewModel>()}
    val adapter  by lazy { scope.get<FirstFragmentAdapter>() }

}
```

When I do this `getKoin().getOrCreateScope(SCOPE_ID, named(SCOPE_ID))`, the app crashes

```
Caused by: org.koin.core.error.NoScopeDefFoundException: No Scope Definition found for qualifer 'FirstFragment'
        at org.koin.core.registry.ScopeRegistry.createScope(ScopeRegistry.kt:128)
        at org.koin.core.Koin.createScope(Koin.kt:181)
        at org.koin.core.Koin.getOrCreateScope(Koin.kt:203)
        at com.temp.testkoin.FirstFragment.<init>(FirstFragment.kt:24)
```

However, if I use `val scope = getKoin().getScopeOrNull(SCOPE_ID)`, scope is set to null.

I went through a few questions on this forum and none of them are similar to what I want to achieve.

- **Question 2:** My Scopes are already created. Why then does `getScopeOrNull()` return null?
- **Question 3:** I even tried doing this and `getScopeOrNull()` still returns null?

```
val featureModule = module {

    scope<FeatureActivity> {

        // FeatureDao
        scope(named("featureDao")) {
            scoped {
                val appDatabase: AppDatabase = get()
                appDatabase.featureDao()
            }
        }

        scope(named(FirstFragment.SCOPE_ID)) {
            scoped { FirstFragmentRepository(get()) }
            viewModel { FirstFragmentViewModel(getScope("featureDao").get()) }
            scoped { FirstFragmentAdapter(get()) }
        }

       ...
       ...

    }
```

- **Question 4:** What's the right way to get a handle on my scope & inject my dependencies properly?
- **Question 5:** Are scopes stable? Removing nested scopes `scope(named(FirstFragment.SCOPE_ID))` and `scope(named(SecondFragment.SCOPE_ID))` gets it going. Works as expected. However, accessing a Bean (from another Scope) in a given Scope isn't yet supported or so it seems. No matter how much I try, it keeps complaining `org.koin.core.error.NoBeanDefFoundException: No definition found for class`

Comment: Hi @nitin i am facing same issue , Did you find any solution for it?